# What's the total rep cap limit on Suggested Edits?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits

According to [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) the limit is 1,000.

> When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the **total cap is 1,000.**

However at least one user has exceeded 1000 points earned from suggested edits.

On these days [Psy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321366/psy?tab=reputation) earned rep from suggested edits

```
9/16 144
9/15 200
9/14 200
9/13 194
9/12 2
9/11 200
9/10 200
```

totaling 1,140 (he earned +2 on other days as well but I stopped looking after it was > 1000)

Comment: Can you link the user who has allegedly earned more than 1000 from suggested edits?

Comment: You're ignoring tag wiki edits

Comment: @GraceNote sure I held back because I didn't want to call it out if the was just that the faq was wrong.

Comment: Looks like someone there found out about the KBD tag and went crazy loco on it

Comment: @random Even tag wiki edits are suggested edits. Only 20k users can edit a tag wiki without the edit gets first approved.

Comment: Holy shiznit, that is a **a lot** of edits in a row hehe

Comment: @random thats what it seems like ‮

Comment: The answer for "How do suggested edits work?" doesn't seems to be updated. As far as I have experienced, for example, as 10k user I can approve any tag wiki edit I have not proposed, independently from the score I have on that tag.

Comment: In my previous comment, I was referring to the following sentences, contained in the answer to that question: "Users with 20k rep, tag leaders and tag bronze badge holders have full editing rights on tag wikis. **They are the only users with the right to approve tag wikis.**"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The total limit is and always was 1000.

However, there was a nasty series of bugs that caused the limit not to be enforced.

The bug is now fixed, which totally sucks for 10 users on SO, that managed to do a ginormous amount of editing and now are going to lose some rep. The worst impacted user will lose upwards of 1000 rep points.

To help diagnose this in future, the [rep report](/reputation) will tell you how close you are to meeting the limit.

> earned XX reputation out of a maximum of 1000 from suggested edits

Comment: to be deployed either today or tomorrow

Comment: I thought it was going to be [closer to 13](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2314/more-than-500-edits)

Comment: 10-13 .. who's counting :) yeah I think you are right