# Is something wrong with the editing reputation?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, edits, suggested-edits

I wonder if someone is experiencing the same as me. My last **+2** reputation coming from an edit was last [December 20th](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/8583212/revisions).

I have edited about 20 more posts since that date like, for example, [DataGridView validation doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/167694) or [Getting the _id of the rows in ListVew right](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/174762) (this is from today). I'm not getting reputation from those edits despite being **Approved** as you can see.

Is Stack Overflow experiencing some problems with the reputation system?

Thanks in advance

**Note:** Reputation from answers and questions are working fine.

Comment: this was fixed recently: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116674/154171, and you were one of [the 13 users to be affected](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2314/more-than-500-edits) - you'll probably lose about 94 reputation next time you recalc too, if you haven't already

Comment: Oh no! My precious reputation!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only earn up to 1,000 reputation from suggesting edits, ever. You are well past that. You will no longer receive reputation from edits. From scanning your profile, it actually appears that you've earned ~20 extra reputation that you shouldn't have. Perhaps a miscalculation, but not a big deal. Just know you've passed your limit.

Comment: Well thanks, I didn't know about the 1,000 limit

Answer (score 5):

According to [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) there is a cap of 1000 rep from edits. Is it possible that you've hit this cap?