# Why don't I get any reputation when I edit a question?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [Is something wrong with the editing reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118215/is-something-wrong-with-the-editing-reputation)

Before I got edit privileges, I was getting +2 reputation for each edit I suggested that got approved. Now that I have full edit privileges, I don't get any reputation. Why would that be?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Past 2,000 reputation, you only get the +2 reputation for edits to tag wikis, up to your maximum of 1,000 reputation for edits. The +2 reputation per edit prior to getting full edit privileges is just to help you gain some reputation up so you can get those privileges and would no longer require approval for the edits you make.