# Reputation not updating?

Tags: support, edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)
>   [Is something wrong with the editing reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118215/is-something-wrong-with-the-editing-reputation)

In the last hour I have done about 15 edits while reviewing on SO, but recieved no reputation?

Were all my edits declined or is it normal that sometimes it can take hour or so to update the reputation. Until now it always took couple of minutes if not less to update it.

Comment: You seem to have hit the 1000 rep max you can gain from edits.

Comment: Several of your edits have not been approced yet. You can see all of your suggested edits here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1647597/marko?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: @Josh Mein, I saw now that review's got accepted, but looks like there is an 1000 reputation limit for editing. Thanks.

Comment: You actually hit the limit a while ago.  You have 544 edits approved, at 2 rep a peace, means that you hit the limit 44 edits ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only gain 1000 reputation via edits, and you have hit that limit.

Comment: Looks like that is the case. Thanks for the answer, I did not know that there is an limit.

Comment: @Marko there is a limit for everything we do in this life my friend