# Zero answer, zero questions, only edits, and a stupid tag wiki

Tags: discussion, users, ethics

Some user comes into the C++ chat room and starts to talk as if he knows us, which makes me look at [his profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961529/ninjaturtle). So the guy, at 105rep, ***has not asked or answered a single question***, made ***[all of his rep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/961529/ninjaturtle?tab=reputation)*** from accepted edits (fine with me), and [some stupid "I was here first!" tag wiki editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11184939/revisions) (not fine with me at all).

Also, when he came to the chat first, [he had the user name "Feeds"](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=4004944#4004944), and even had the fitting avatar with it (which severely [confused us](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=4004986#4004986) at first), but he [claimed he didn't know it would be considered bad](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/10?m=4004952#4004952) to do that.

Call me suspicious, emulously competitive, and a grumpy, humorless old man but I can't help it. The guy does come across like cheating his way through SO on so many levels, I just have to ask whether this behavior is considered Ok or not.

Comment: "this" behaviour... which bit?

Comment: @jadarnel27 That's _not_ the Programmers.SE chatroom, it's a chat.so room similarly named.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Oh, I didn't know this room mirrors one on chat.SE. Trying to populate his chatroom by having it mirror a popular other room seems to fit with the rest of him, though.

Comment: @AakashM: "The guy does come across like cheating his way through SO on so many levels"

Comment: He's also had two whole comments! One of which just advertised his chat room and I've cast a flag upon...

Comment: Well, we can't know for sure he's knows about [The Whiteboard](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), ProgSE's main chatroom... It's not like it's a very unique name, and his room is missing the "the". That said, something doesn't smell quite right about this one.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Just like he might indeed have accidentally picked the username "Feeds" including [this avatar](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/feed-icon32.png). Yeah. He might.

Comment: I strongly disagree with people choosing misleading user names.

Comment: His rep is strange to be sure, but there's nothing inherently wrong with that.  Being "Feeds" and claiming he "didn't know" (even if it is a lie) is also not inherently wrong to me.  I'd say he hasn't done anything "wrong" yet, but I'd keep an eye on him.

Comment: @DiscountGucciHandbags are you saying that you really do have Discount Gucci Handbags?  or is that misleading?

Comment: Wow, looks like I have lots of edits to roll back tonight... just another user mindlessly using backticks for quoting keywords.

Comment: I wish I could personally tell the people off who approved those edits... "improved formatting" my hoof.

Comment: *"Call me suspicious, emulously competitive, and a grumpy, humorless old man"*  I think ***C++ developer*** is sufficient.

Comment: I've got an answer pending for this, @sbi, but I'm just doing some internal double-checking with regards to the Feeds deal.

Comment: My inclination is to frown upon such behavior, but to treat it as non-malicious until it can be shown that the user knows it is frowned upon. Yeah, that probably gives some obnoxious, trolling jerks an undeserved break, but it also avoids landing on the innocently clueless like a ton of rectangular building things.

Comment: @BoltClock: I hadn't even looked at those edits. Now that I did, it seems most of them were simply stupid. So add to all this that he got lots of rep from edits that should never have been approved and gained him rep. And also add that he's probably suggested a lot more edits, all of which have been disapproved, so he also needlessly drained the human resources of the site. I am sorry, but this all comes down to him not exactly being an asset of the site.

Comment: @Won't: _Weak smile._ I wish. Those hipster folks we get in the lounge lately, though...

Comment: @dmckee: My inclination is the same, but it just kept piling up around that guy, so I felt I wanted to have a public opinion on him.

Comment: I wanted to correct "emulously" to "enormously", but it turns out the former is actually a word. Learn something new every day...

Comment: "*I think **C++** developer is sufficient.*" - @Won't I think you misspelled "PHP" =)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta: I have to admit that I found it through [a dictionary](http://dict.leo.org) myself. `:-/` Not being a native, I sometimes do not know whether I hadn't known of an English word because I hadn't paid enough attention, or because nobody ever uses it.

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I have never heard of emulously :P

Comment: this might be a sign that you care a little too much about StackOverflow...

Comment: @DeadMG: Like you'd be the one we non-natives would measure our mastery of English against!

Comment: And that, @Alex, might be a sign that you know too little of me. `:)`

Comment: @MikeB: Yeah, right, this is all about me being jealous. BTW. do you know a way for me to get the guy's 106rep once he gets strafed? I have earned it, after all, haven't I? (Really, do we indeed have to talk about this? You are boring me. I rarely ever answer nowadays, and I still have days where I get >100rep — just from old answers.)

Comment: @MikeB: It's all right there in the question, you only have to read: "The guy does come across like cheating his way through SO on so many levels, I just have to ask whether this behavior is considered Ok or not."

Comment: @MikeB It's good for the community at large to know about policies, so they can know how to act in the future (when / how to flag, if anything should be done at all, etc).  That's why posts like this one are useful (and this *was* useful, an SE employee answered with specific policies / guidance).  Mentioning the specific person is important as well because, without examples, it sounds like an imagined problem.

Comment: thanks @MikeB for expressing in a meta-appropriate way what i suggested (and that was cancelled, but hey).

Comment: @Mike: He came into the chat mimicking the Feed user to the point we're confused. He earned the rep necessary for that by making pointless (or even disruptive) edits, presumably suggesting much more than those which made it through the review process, which bound precious human review resources. He tries to lure users into his pointless chatroom, which mimics the name of a famous SE chatroom. None of this is bad by itself, but all in all it makes him the opposite of an asset for SO. Now please tell me: Where should I have flagged this and how explained all of it to an overworked moderator?

Comment: Hey, it seems [his account has been closed since](http://stackoverflow.com/users/961529/), and his activities now link to [some other account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/514945/) instead. I guess that means there was something fishy with that account?

Comment: what worries me slightly is a) that experienced users as @sbi do not seem to know how to deal properly with these things (and how could a new user be, even if reading the faq?), and b) that the other users at this question do not seem to have a problem with singleing out a user and naming and shaming them, e.g. up-voting this question or the comments

Comment: @Mike: This isn't 4chan, it's MSO, so I wasn't expecting a flash mob, but a mod chiming in and explaining their POV on the issue — which, not surprisingly, is exactly what happened. However, if you _still_ think his rep was of concern to me, then we don't need to continue this discussion, because despite several iterations (and numerous explaining comments already present before you came to this discussion), I seem to be unable to get my point across to you.

Comment: @Andrea: The account you are currently posting under makes it seem like you'd better listen and learn. Since your behavior indicates experience, would you mind to explain which account's experience you base your opinion on?

Comment: No, @Mike, I am not referring to comments of others trying to prove any case.

Comment: @MikeB: sbi was 100% certain of his opinion and the user's guilt yes.  His question was "whether [the user's] behavior is considered Ok or not."  This is very clearly not a personal attack so much as a rule clarification.  The question stands even if he hadn't linked to a particular user's profile.

Comment: On virtually every meta question, people demand links to the context to judge for themselves, which is an excellent idea.  How can we judge without context?  Also, several comments in this thread show that it wasn't clear that the user had broken any rules, and that sbi's intended question is justified.

Comment: Well, @Mike, despite the fact that you seemed to never even have understood why I was asking, despite the fact that you are the first here who considered it "VERY OBVIOUS" that the guy has been against the rules (in hind view, of course...), whereas many others needed to ask first, and read explanatory comments from me, and despite the fact that several mods from several SE sites, SE employees, and meta regulars didn't seem to have your problem with my question, you keep insisting this question is totally wrong and I am, essentially, an asshole.

Comment: Of course, given your incredibly high reputation here, I will now hang my head in shame, delete this whole question, and promise to never do something like this again. _Snort._ (And now please flag this as offensive, so that a mod gets aware of this silly discussion and can delete it.) Too bad, really, we can only plonk in the chat. _HAND._

Comment: @Mike: _Snort._ In the first of your "model posts", the second comment named the user (and otherwise the name would have been asked in the very next comment), in the second question, the victim couldn't have known who dunnit, the third _does_ link to the controversy (and thus to the in question) right in the question, and the fourth is about two specific types of recurring behavior, rather than one concrete case. That is pathetic. And now please stop wasting my attention by swamping my inbox with this increasingly useless discussion.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Full disclosure: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/3588/grace-note

In the case you bring up, it appears from most people that many of the edits were actually pretty bad and should never have been accepted. Unfortunately, there isn't much safeguard against that in the system, and there's little comfort for the future can do as far as alleviating the existing damage. All that can be done is to keep an eye out to prevent any future poor edits from getting through.

Assuming that the user is actually making *good edits*, though, accruing reputation through suggested edits alone, I believe, is entirely acceptable and not cheating the system. It's a legitimate avenue to contribute to the community.

Keep in mind, though, that any such climb is not only slow (+2 per edit is a lot less than the loosely limited potential of post voting), but restricted to a maximum of 1000 reputation. So while they'll get a good start, they won't even be able to earn any of the major privilege capabilities such as full blown editing or close voting. Helpful or otherwise, they'll have to start providing more solid contributions in the form of questions and answers to get any further.

---

As for the avatar/name issue, dmckee sums it up best in his comment:

> My inclination is to frown upon such behavior, but to treat it as non-malicious until it can be shown that the user knows it is frowned upon. Yeah, that probably gives some obnoxious, trolling jerks an undeserved break, but it also avoids landing on the innocently clueless like a ton of rectangular building things.

After some internal discussion, users mimicking actual system accounts (Community, Feeds, etc.) is equivalent to impersonating a moderator or an SE Employee, which is **officially disallowed**. However, we'll still work on good faith, so unless they're being outwardly malicious in intent, it's something we can just softly advise them to stop doing as they go forwards.

Comment: I have to ask -- where is the only-1000-rep-for-editing limit documented? Is there a list of similar such limits that aren't widely known?

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that is limited. Still, 1k of rep would take 500 edit suggestions that need to be approved or discarded, which, if they are all dumb, needlessly drains resources from more important issues. (And that's why I think his edits do not compare at all to yours, which are a _contribution_ to the community.) Add to this the time we spent on the user name/avatar issue, and any classic _help vampire_ seems to be a nice chap compared to this mischievous guy.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill It's definitely in the "[How do suggested edits work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)" faq post.  I don't know if it's anywhere else, though.

Comment: @sbi For what it's worth, enough rejected edits will automatically suspend someone from making suggested edits for 7 days.

Comment: Full disclosure?  Huh?

Comment: @Wont I have earned 500 invincible reputation on GameDev through nothing but suggested edits to posts and wikis. Mostly wikis. Basically, the disclosure is to note that I have actually done this behavior, and while I don't personally use it to justify the policy on it, it's still important to air it out in advance.

Comment: Just imagine all the abusive privileges Grace Note has earned with that 500 rep!

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill here's a [person complaining](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118215/is-something-wrong-with-the-editing-reputation?lq=1) when they've hit the limit. Which came after I noticed the limit [wasn't being enforced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116650/148672).

Comment: Oh, while we're at it, the FAQ on every site also states explicitly: "You can only earn a maximum of +1000 total reputation through suggested edits, however." It's not intended to be hidden or surprising, so putting it in our main bed of instructions seemed like the best place.

Comment: @GraceNote Hm? I thought the FAQ was where we were hiding stuff, it's not like anyone will ever read it...

Comment: @Grace this reminds me of something that happened long ago - what about users mimicking high rep users by taking their name and avatar? Should this be reported via a flag? Surely people can see the low reputation and everything, but still..

Comment: FYI, Grace: The guy is still [wasting meta's resources](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138481/133368).

Comment: If it's "officially disallowed" to use misleading user names, why not ban it? I.e. change the system so that you cannot create an account with a misleading user name. feeds, community, Stack Overflow employee names, etc.

Comment: _which is officially disallowed_ mmm, couple months ago I reported a guy whose name was "stackoverflow" and nobody did anything...

Comment: @ajax333221 "stackoverflow" isn't an official system account, or the name used by any employee or used as part of impersonating a moderator.

Answer (score 9):

To add some closure to this - the user in question - going under the name NinjaTurtle was actually an account created by a [different user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/514945/manjotsingh) to avoid a 1 year Stack Overflow and chat ban. So suspicious behaviour like this is part of flagging and identifying abuse.

Answer (score -5):

You're a suspicious, emulously competitive, and a grumpy, humorless old man.

Complaining about how a person managed to gain a total of 105 rep points is extremely niggardly.

> and some stupid "I was here first!" tag wiki editing (not fine with me
>   at all).

If the community was more active in doing tag wikis, this problem wouldn't occur in the first place.

Comment: I don't think that was really the main point. The user in question's edits spawned a couple highly voted Meta posts

Comment: It's good to see you raising to the bait of accusing me to be a "suspicious, emulously competitive, and a grumpy, humorless old man" _in such a wonderfully humorous fashion_. If it wasn't for that, someone might get the idea you could not have gotten the point of that bait. And we wouldn't want this, would we?

Comment: @sbi I used a word that's rarely used in English ("niggardly"), just like you did in your question. Doesn't that count?

Comment: Programmers, really. Think they're funny because they applied a word rarely used. _Groans._