# What can we do about large amounts of plagiarizing in tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

I've recently noticed, by one user in particular, a rash of tag wiki updates where the text is copied verbatim from either Wikipedia, documentation or another website.  Some examples are below:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/299898

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/299076

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/299077

In some cases, the tag wikis were approved without anyone noticing the copy-and-paste approach.

When we see something like this, what is the best approach to take?  Clear out the tag wikis of approved tags?  Notify a moderator so they can talk with the user?  Something else?

Comment: The current dupe target ([Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79000/335251)) doesn't seem like it really matches this question; that question asks if this behavior is okay, but doesn't address what to do about it after the fact. That said, it looks like other discussions about the same thing have also been closed as a duplicate of the same post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has just occurred to me that this question is probably one with the [recent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137744/2509) series on [what to do](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137784/2509) about users [gaining points by spamming the edit queues with poor edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137755/2509), so I've updated the treatment a bit.

---

### Concerning the content

If the content is good and if the source license allows re-use (as Wikipedia does, I believe), then make sure it is properly cited it and move on.

If the content is bad or the source does not allow re-use then it will have to go.

### Concerning the edit points

If the content is good, then who cares?

If it is bad, we'll have to roll it back.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to properly cite in the excerpt as opposed to the wiki? [For example this one](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/modula-3/info)

Comment: I believe that markup in general is discouraged in the except so it might be best to write a it in your own words. You can always put a cited passage in the full wiki.